# Chrome/Safari/Firefox JavaScript change date format automatically to DD-MM-YYYY format

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox, safari

I have recently applied for unitymedia internet services in Germany (I am moving there in about a month - I currently live in the US). They sent me a confirmation email in which I have to type in my birth date. However, they only accept the DD.MM.YYYY format. The problem is that when I type my birth date in that format it gets automatically changed to a DD-MM-YYYY format and the web page accuses an "invalid format". I can use whatever format and the Java script automatically detects the date and changes it to DD-MM-YYYY.

I tried in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and they all show the same problem. Changing browser language to German doesn't fix the problem. I also changed the operational system (I use a Mac OS) language to German and it doesn't help. Also tried using the "inspect" feature in Chrome but I am no expert, unfortunately.

If I disable java altogether (or use a java script blocker in chrome) then I am finally able to type in the date (and keep it) in the DD.MM.YYYY format, however, then after hitting the proceed button the web page cannot proceed any further, I guess because the following pages depend on Java.

Any ideas or workarounds to this problem?

Comment: java? or javascript? anyway, looks like the issue is either line 37, or with some web page that you have no control over - so, you need to contact *unitymedia internet services in Germany* and explain to them that their web page doesn't work for you

Comment: javascript. Sorry, as I mentioned, I am *far* from an expert. What do you mean by line 37?

Comment: I thought it was a problem with my javascript configuration, not with the page itself. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: line 37 was a "joke" - anyway, without any code, any links, nothing to go on at all, and you don't even own the page/site you have an issue with, your only recourse is to contact the company whose website is written so horribly

Comment: @FábioPereiraSantos—it is an issue with the script in the page, nothing to do with your browser settings (Safari doesn't support input type Date so it can't be that). You will have to contact them by some other means. Welcome to the world of bad UIs, there are plenty of them. You might have to reboot your computer into German and check regional settings are the correct format, javascript itself doesn't do any of that.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for the clarification! It is a really annoying problem. I talked with a German friend and she is doing it for me in her computer. Sad I had to resort to this solution... Best